# selectField with store in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Hi my selectfield structure is as follow :

```
{
  xtype: 'selectfield',
  label: 'Name :',
  name: 'description',
  displayField: 'description',
  valueField: '_description',
  store: 'ABC',
  autoSelect: true,
  labelWidth:'35%',
  readOnly:true
}
```

How I can set Default value as --select--
Is this possible.
Please guide me or provide working code thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `placeholder`:

```
{
    xtype: 'selectfield',
    placeholder: '--select--',
    ...
}
```

See docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.field.Input-cfg-placeHolder

Comment: I believe this is just for aesthetic purposes, to give an idea of what the field is about only whilst it is empty. E.g. a search field having "Enter search words here..."

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actual value to be set in the field, i.e. 'default value' as you ask, you can  set the default value on the model, e.g.

```
Ext.define('Core.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'description', type: 'string', defaultValue: '--select--' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then on your store 'ABC' make sure the model is set correctly i.e. `model: 'Core.model.MyModel`.

If you just want a placeholder label to appear saying '--select--' - purely for decorative/aesthetic purposes, not an actual value that would then be used, then kevhender's answer is correct, i.e. the `placeholder` property.

Comment: Since I have used  " autoSelect: true," placeholder dose not works.Basically what I want is this select field display default value as --select-- and when I click on it I can able to select values from given store.

Comment: That is because when autoSelect is true, it will try and select the first value in the store, whatever that is.

Comment: Yup Correct.So even though when autoSelect is true can we have default custom value by  any way..

Comment: You can, using 'defaultValue' on the model. But that means that '--select--' will be an actual string value for the 'description' field, so someone could potentially submit a form with the value '--select--' in it, unless you add in some custom validation later on to stop that from happening. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-defaultValue. You may just want a visual placeholder, in which case don't set autoSelect:true.